# Adding new row in Crosstab Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I would like to know if it is possible to add/place a row within a crosstab report.

For example, I am making a Profit and Loss Report using Crystal Reports 2011 for SAP. I would like to add a row below "Cost of Goods Sold Total" where I can place a row for Gross Profit which will be calculated from Income Total - Cost of Goods Sold Total.
(see attached image)

[image]

Let me know if this is possible. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing a similar problem, I found a solution.

1) Right-click the 'Row' with the title '2' > Select Calculated Member > Insert Row. You should see a new Row with zero values below the row '2'.

2) Right-click the 1st blank space below '2' and select Calculated Member > Edit Header formula and type in:

```
"Gross Profit"
```

3) Then, right-click one of the zero values in the row and select Calculated Member > Edit Calculation Formula and use this code:

```
GridValueAt(GetRowPathIndexOf(1), CurrentColumnIndex, CurrentSummaryIndex) -
GridValueAt(GetRowPathIndexOf(2), CurrentColumnIndex, CurrentSummaryIndex)
```